How to avoid "not enough information to infer relation" in drizzle with many-to-many junction table
I am trying to create a many-to-many relation in the Drizzle ORM schema using a PostgreSQL junction table. In other similar questions users suggest to add relation names on "both sides" of the relation, which I have, and behavior didn't change. Many examples were for one-to-many not many-to-many. I am getting the error Error: There is not enough information to infer relation "TemplateDefinitions.colorSets"
I added relation names to "both sides" of the main relation, error remaining the same. I also tried adding relation names to the relation() definition for the junction table itself, but drizzle then indicated that there are multiple relations with the same name.
The TLDR of the relationship is the templateDefinitions have many colorSets, and colorSets have many templateDefinitions. The relevant section of my schema is below, including addition of relation names.
Update: I tried adding the relation names to all other MTM relationships and all fail with similar error. Query using "with" on one-to-many relationships works fine.
    export const TemplateDefinitions = pgTable('template_definitions', {
      id: uuid('id').primaryKey().defaultRandom(),
      name: varchar('name', { length: 256 }).notNull(),
    })
    
    // template has many color sets, color sets have many templates
    export const templateDefinitionToColorSets = pgTable(
      'template_definition_to_color_sets',
      {
        templateDefinitionId: uuid('template_definition_id')
          .references((): AnyPgColumn => TemplateDefinitions.id)
          .notNull(),
        colorSetId: uuid('color_set_id')
          .references(() => ColorSets.id)
          .notNull(),
      },
      (table) => ({
        pk: primaryKey({ columns: [table.templateDefinitionId, table.colorSetId] }),
      })
    )
    
    export const templateDefinitionToColorSetsRelations = relations(
      templateDefinitionToColorSets,
      ({ one }) => ({
        colorSet: one(ColorSets, {
          fields: [templateDefinitionToColorSets.colorSetId],
          references: [ColorSets.id],
        }),
        templateDefinition: one(TemplateDefinitions, {
          fields: [templateDefinitionToColorSets.templateDefinitionId],
          references: [TemplateDefinitions.id],
        }),
      })
    )
    
    export const templateDefinitionRelations = relations(
      TemplateDefinitions,
      ({ one, many }) => ({
        // template definitions have many templates (instances)
        templates: many(Templates),
        // template definitions only have token definitions, no token instances. Whereas template instances have both token definitions and token instances.
        tokenDefinitions: many(templateToTokenDefinitions),
        categories: many(templateDefinitionToCategories, {
          relationName: 'templateDefinitionToCategories',
        }),
        colorSets: many(templateDefinitionToColorSets, {
          relationName: 'templateDefinitionToColorSets',
        }),
      })
    )
    
    // COLOR SETS
    // A color set is a collection of colors that represent a theme for a template definition. A template definition can have many color sets. A color set can have one template definition.
    
    export const ColorSets = pgTable('color_sets', {
      id: uuid('id').primaryKey().defaultRandom(),
      name: varchar('name', { length: 256 }).notNull(),
    })
    
    export const colorSetRelations = relations(ColorSets, ({ one, many }) => ({
      colors: many(Color),
      templateDefinitions: many(templateDefinitionToColorSets, {
        relationName: 'templateDefinitionToColorSets',
      }),
    }))

The error arises when I open drizzle studio or when I try to query in the code as follows:
const templateDefinition = await db.query.TemplateDefinitions.findFirst({
    where: eq(TemplateDefinitions.id, id),
        with: {
            colorSets: {
                with: {
                    colorSet: true,
                },
            },
        },
    })


I finally figured it out (sort of).
relationName in config objects are seemingly only for one-to-many relationships. Adding a relationName to the one-to-many relation in the first definition allowed Drizzle to disambiguate all adjacent relations. Many-to-many relations seem to not need relationName and should simply point to their junction table on each side. The following two blocks work perfectly.
export const templateDefinitionRelations = relations(
  TemplateDefinitions,
  ({ one, many }) => ({
    templates: many(Templates, {
      relationName: 'templateDefTemplates', /* YES CONFIG (one-to-many) */
    }),
    colorSets: many(templateDefinitionToColorSets), /* NO CONFIG (many-to-many) */
  })
)

const templateDefinition = await db.query.TemplateDefinitions.findFirst({
  where: eq(TemplateDefinitions.id, id),
  with: {
    colorSets: true,
  },
})

Although this behavior seems inconsistent and still confuses me. On the other relation for colorSets there is a one to many relation where querying works with no relationName, but breaks if you add a relationName. Example:
export const colorSetRelations = relations(ColorSets, ({ one, many }) => ({
  colors: many(Color, {
    relationName: 'colorSetColors', /* BREAKS 'with' query, remove to work */
  }),
  templateDefinitions: many(templateDefinitionToColorSets),
}))

const colorSet = await db.query.ColorSets.findFirst({
  with: {
    templateDefinitions: true,
  },
})

I wish I could provide more technical insight on what exactly causes relations to have these behaviors, but I wanted to put this up for readers since I had so much trouble finding any info on these issues at all. If you are feeling up to it you can read the library code on GitHub that processes relations and generates relevant errors.
Note to future readers: Drizzle plans to release a V2 of the Relations API with new features and new configuration API. This may not be valid in the future
